# What is the easiest way to make template function code depending on the parameter type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, sfinae

I want to write a template function that checks some Timestamp property (class inherits from `Timed`) but also has to work for types that do not have a timestamp. The best (and still quite ugly) solution I have found is the following:

```
class Timed {
  protected:
    int mTime;        
  public:
    explicit Timed(int time=0): mTime(time){}
    int getT() const {return mTime;}

};

template<typename T>
bool checkStale(T const* ptr) const {
  return checkStaleImp(ptr, boost::is_base_of<Timed, T>() );
}

template<typename T>
template<bool b>
bool checkStaleImp(T const* ptr, boost::integral_constant<bool, b> const &){
  return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool checkStaleImp(T const* ptr, boost::true_type const&){
  const int oldest = 42;
  return (42 <= ptr->getT());  
}
```

This is three functions for one functionality. Is there an easier way to accomplish this, e.g. use `boost::is_base_of` or sth. similar in an if condition or boost::enable if to turn the function output into a sort of constant for classes not deriving from `Timed`. Solutions with virtual functions are unfortunately not an option.

Comment: @AJG85: The actual functions are members of a class template (left out to shorten example) so the question of template or not is obsolete, but reading the answer of fernandes I think a far simpler solution is possible

Comment: That was the point of the comment. To get you thinking about alternatives like overloads etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the same thing with two simple overloads and no template machinery:

```
bool checkStale(void const* ptr){
  return true;
}

bool checkStale(Timed const* ptr){
  const int oldest = 42;
  return (oldest <= ptr->getT());  
}
```

No need for tag dispatching on `is_base_of`.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. He also could have a single full specialization of the template function for `Timed` to similar effect.

Comment: I think this will not work. The derived class of `Timed` will instantiate the function template, instead of calling the overload with parameter `Timed const*`.

Comment: @Nawaz good point. I should have just taken out all the templates :S

Comment: Now this looks correct as far as compiler is concerned. +1. But what if the first function has implementation which depends on type? In my answer, I thought `return true` is there to reduce verbosity in the question, and its actual implementation depends on T.

Comment: @Nawaz: yes, that would require an actual template. But I believen that's not the case, because the OP says he wants to "turn the function output into a sort of constant for classes not deriving from Timed"

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is *quite ugly* solution, as you said. However, you can reduce the scope of helper functions if you implement them as static member of local class as:

```
template<typename T>
bool checkStale(T const* ptr) const 
{
  struct local
  {
      static bool checkStaleImp(T const* ptr, boost::false_type const &)
      {
         return true;
      }
      static bool checkStaleImp(T const* ptr, boost::true_type const&)
      {
        const int oldest = 42;
        return (42 <= ptr->getT());  
      }
  };
  return local::checkStaleImp(ptr, boost::is_base_of<Timed, T>());
}
```

Now, there is one function exposed for the user, and the actual implementation inside the local class.

By the way, in C++11, you can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) instead of boost's version. Same with `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue with my answer instead of upvoting it. Have a +1.

Comment: Interesting approach and neater. If I'm not mistaken your code misses a static. For me exposure was not an issue since all three functions are private class members (left out for simplicity) but nonetheless interesting

Answer (score 0):

Use `enable_if` to select between possible overloads. Since the conditions used in the following example are complimentary there will always be exactly one overload available, and therefore no ambiguity

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Timed,T>::value,bool>::type
checkStale(T const *ptr) const {
    const int oldest = 42;
    return oldest <= ptr->getT();
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Timed,T>::value,bool>::type
checkStale(T const *ptr) const {
    return true;
}
```